# Form to send information to different pages according to which button you push

Tags: php, forms, select, button, input

So I have this form with a dropdown list and two buttons. I want to be able to select something from the dropdown list and send that information to two different pages depending on which button I press.

```
    <form action="(edit_user.php or create_user.php)" method="POST">
        <select id="dropdown" name="users" size="30">
            <option value="user1">Joe</option>
            <option value="user2">Jane</option>
            <option value="user3">Snuffy</option>
            <option value="user4">Mahabirsinghmatos</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Create User" />
        <input type="submit" value="Edit User" />
    </form>
```

I want to send the form information to one of those two php files according to which button I pressed.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the submit buttons names:

```
<input type="submit" name="task" value="Create User" />
<input type="submit" name="task" value="Edit User" />
```

Have the PHP script that handles your `action` determine which file to run it though.

e.g.

```
if (!isset($_POST['task'])) {
    # Some default action
} elseif ($_POST['task'] == "Edit User") {
    include('edit_user.php');
} elseif ($_POST['task'] == "Create User") {
    include('create_user.php');
} else {
    # Some error state
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `action`-property for the form in the submit-button `onclick`-events :

add some ids to the form and the buttons :

```
 <form action="(edit_user.php or create_user.php)" method="POST" id="theForm">
        <select id="dropdown" name="users" size="30">
            <option value="user1">Joe</option>
            <option value="user2">Jane</option>
            <option value="user3">Snuffy</option>
            <option value="user4">Mahabirsinghmatos</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Create User" id="btnCreate"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit User" id="btnEdit"/>
    </form>
```

script :

```
var form = document.getElementById('theForm');
document.getElementById('btnCreate').onclick = function() {
    form.action='create_user.php';
}
document.getElementById('btnEdit').onclick = function() {
    form.action='edit_user.php';
}
```